# How to keep dual monitor setting after reboot (with gnome, gdm, wayland)

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, gdm, wayland

I would like to recover my previous monitors configuration when my computer boots with an external monitor plugged in. It works out of the box with `lightdm`, `gnome`, and `X session`, it's not the case with `gdm` and `wayland`.

---

Expected behavior :

- remember previous configuration to automatically switch to external screen (only) on session opening on boot  if my monitor is plugged.